# Extract Time Domain double[] of Wav file for input into FFT - Java

Tags: java, audio, fft, wav

I have a wav file and can't figure out how to extract the data I need from it to put it into an Fast Fourier Transform (FFT) for further analysis...

I've done lots of googling and searching but haven't found something specific...

```
The FFT algorithm code:

    public class ShortTimeFourierTransform {
        public static double[][] magnitudeSpectrum(double[] signal, int windowSize, int hopSize) { ... }  
...}
```

Takes in a double[] for the signal so I assumed that I had to figure out how to parse the wav file and get a double[t] where "t" is the time, and double[t] would be the amplitude of the wav file at time t.

I have no idea how to proceed. Most solutions seem to export the wav into bytes and the parsing of wav files by bytes seems to be a lot more complicated manually according to (https://ccrma.stanford.edu/courses/422/projects/WaveFormat/)

Thank you so much!

Comment: I have the same problem today. Dammit... https://xkcd.com/979/

Answer (score 1):

The .wav format is just a wrapper format around an audio encoding.  You'll need to:

- Parse the .wav file, get the encoded audio
- Decode the audio, get raw PCM audio bytes (PCM is also an encoding but easy to work with)
- Convert the audio into whatever format you requires. (some doubles?)

There's no real way around this- unless you can change the format of the file.

If you can change the file format, I suggest using a program (like Audacity) to open the wav file, and save its raw PCM encoded bytes.  That'll keep you from having to worry about the .wav format.

A good 3rd party library can help you with this.  I have no suggestions though.